# Using jquery data attributes with each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, custom-data-attribute

I'm building a quote generator, and there is a product field where a user can select a product, select the quantity, then add another if they wish.

I'm using an each function to loop through all the products they add to sum the price.

For regular values, my JS is running great, but I want to add a second price (minimum price) that the product can be sold for. I've added the data as an attribute and i'm trying to use the same method to pull the price from the attribute, but it just keeps returning 'undefined'!!!!

HTML

```
<select class="form-control onChangePrice system1" name="SystemModel">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="3300" data-min-price="3000">System 1</option>
  <option value="4500" data-min-price="4000">System 2</option>
  <option value="6000" data-min-price="5500">System 3</option>
  <option value="6000" data-min-price="5500">System 4</option>
</select>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <input class="form-control onChangePrice systemNumber" type="number" name="SystemModelAmount" value="1">
</div>
```

JS

```
 var systemTotal = 0;
 var systemMin = 0;
 var i = 0;
 $('.system1').each(function(){
  if (this.value != "") {
    systemEachMin = $(this).data("minPrice");
    console.log(systemEachMin);
    systemEachTotal = this.value * parseInt($(".systemNumber").eq(i).val());
    systemTotal += parseFloat(systemEachTotal);
    systemMin += parseFloat(systemEachMin);
  };
  i++;
});
```

The code works flawlessly for the regular value of the option, i just cant get it to repeat for the data attribute!

Thanks

Comment: `systemEachMin = $(this).attr("data-min-price");`. Alos your code is not full.  `$(".systemNumber")` html is missing

Comment: or `$(this).data("min-price")`

Comment: I've tried both of these, it just keeps returning 'undefined'. I've looked into camel case issues with the function but no matter what i do, it keeps returning 'undefined'

Comment: `$('.system1').each` is looping each `<select>` element, not each `<option>` element. Your select doesn't have the data attribute. To get the selected option you would use something like `$(this).find(':selected')`

Comment: Brilliant @Partick Evans, thank you! `systemEachMin = $(this).find(':selected').data("min-price");` How come I don't have to use the selected attribute when targeting the value? but i do when targeting the attribute?

Comment: because `HTMLSelectElement.value` is just a copy of the value of the currently selected option in that select. `this` still references the select element itself, not the option element.

Comment: @Sam can you review the answers and accept the one that works please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(this).data("minPrice"); refers to the select tag and not the options tag, there is no data-min-price on the select tag.

this.options will return all the options in an array

or you could use the following for the selected options data attribute

$(this).find('option:selected').data("minPrice")

or

$("option:selected", this).data("minPrice")

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a couple of things slightly wrong here:

```
$('.system1').each(function(){
```

should be:

```
$('.system1 option').each(function(){
```

**and**

```
systemEachMin = $(this).data("minPrice");
```

should be:

```
systemEachMin = $(this).data("min-price");
```

**So in full:**

```
var systemTotal = 0;
 var systemMin = 0;
 var i = 0;
 $('.system1 option').each(function(){
  if (this.value != "") {
    systemEachMin = $(this).data("min-price");
    console.log(systemEachMin);
    systemEachTotal = this.value * parseInt($(".systemNumber").eq(i).val());
    systemTotal += parseFloat(systemEachTotal);
    systemMin += parseFloat(systemEachMin);
  };
  i++;
});
```

Comment: And there is only one `input.systemNumber`, so `$(".systemNumber").eq(i).val()` is wrong too (except if the HTML isn't full here)